# What are the benefits of using the 'concat' method over 'push' for concatenating arrays in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, concatenation, push

`concat(array)` vs `push(...array)`

I've been using `.push(...)` method to concatenate 2 arrays unpacking the second array, using the three dots notation, and passing that as the argument (`array1.push(...array2)`). But I just noticed that `.concat(...)` does the same thing, at least as far as I know.

I just want to know what are the benefits of using one over the other, if any, aside from `.concat(...)` being more idiomatic.

Comment: The internal mechanics are probably almost completely identical, use whichever you thinks looks better. Let the people who are paid to maintain and improve the JavaScript runtimes worry about micro-efficiency.

Comment: `push()` mutates the array you're pushing to while `concat()` creates a new array with the elements of both arrays, leaving the original array intact. So it's a matter of the side-effects you want (or don't want).

Comment: You may run into `SyntaxError: too many function arguments` using `.push(…arr)` if arr is very long.

Comment: I don't quite follow the question, it would be **much** clearer if you gave a proper example of each of the two things you're trying to do. If you want to create a new array containing the elements of an existing array followed by the elements of another existing array, you shouldn't use `push` at all. You should use either `result = first.concat(second)` or `result = [...first, ...second]`.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder I just discovered the `concat()` method, before that I was simply using `push()` for everything and worked just fine, and since it was only for some university assignments I just did not bother too much about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JavaScript engines typically put a cap on the number of arguments you can pass to a method before they throw an error, for example, the below throws an error in Chrome:

```js
const arr = Array(150000).fill(0);
const arr2 = [];
arr2.push(...arr);
```

Whereas when using `.concat()`, you'll only be passing the one array to the method, so you don't get the error:

```js
const arr = Array(150000).fill(0);
const arr2 = [];
const res = arr2.concat(arr);
// res is an array with 150000 `0`s
```

Additionally, with `.push()` + `...`, you're effectively doing two iterations over your iterable/array, one for unpacking its contents as arguments to the `.push()` method, and then another for one done internally by the `.push()` method itself to iterate through each of the arguments and append it to the target array.

Another noticeable difference is in what both methods return, `.concat()` will return a new array and won't modify the target, which can be useful in methods such as `.map()` or `.reduce()` where you need to produce a new array without mutating the original. Whereas `.push()` will return the length of the updated array and will modify the target, so that is another difference to consider.

As pointed out by [@T.J. Crowder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157247/t-j-crowder), the [iterator of arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/@@iterator) which is invoked when using the spread syntax `...` does not preserve blanks in sparse arrays, instead it unpacks them as `undefined` values, meaning that if the array you're specifying is sparse when using `.push()` + `...` you'll get `undefined` for the blanks, whereas the blanks will be preserved when using `.concat()` directly:

```js
const arr = Array(3); // this is a sparse array, [empty × 3], not to be confused with [undefined, undefined, undefined]
const arr2 = [];
arr2.push(...arr); // Here `...` becomes: arr2.push(undefined, undefined, undefined);
console.log(arr2); // [undefined, undefined, undefined]

const arr3 = [];
console.log(arr3.concat(arr)); // Retains empties: [empty × 3]
```

```html
See browser console for results
```

Comment: There's also the fact `concat` preserves gaps in sparse arrays, while using `push` as above (or using spread) will replace the gaps with actual elements having the value `undefined`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder oh yes, thanks for pointing that out also :). I’ll update my answer to highlight that difference also (although it won’t be for some time as I’m off to sleep now)

Answer (score 0):

The big difference that `push()` adds elements to an array, but `concat()` returns a new array.
Recently after been working with Vue I found that it's important keep object variables as intact as possible and declare them with `const`.

This allows not losing references to the original objects and promotes reactive programming.
For me currently that's a very important concept. It allows me to be relaxed regarding whether any object reference could be broken if code is very modular.

The only problem that spread arguments are slow and not save with big arrays so I wouldn't mind to monkeypatch `Array.prototype.append` with my custom benchmarked implementation.

For example:

```js
class Some{
  constructor(source){
    this.arr = source;
  }
  push(...elems){
    this.arr.push(...elems);
  }
}

let source = []; // that's bad for me, I use const now as much as possible

const some = new Some(source);

// step 1: using push
source.push(...[0, 0, 0]);
some.push(...[1, 1, 1]);

console.log(source.join());
console.log(some.arr.join());

// step 1: using concat, here the original array link is lost
source = source.concat([2, 2, 2]);

// hmm, one would expect them to be equal...
console.log(source.join());
console.log(some.arr.join());
```

An example how the appending could be implemented, it's faster than pushing (there's also some boost because of pre-allocating new elements).

```js
    const arr = Array(10000000).fill(0);
    
    Array.prototype.append = function(arr){
    
        this.length += arr.length;
        for(let i = 0, j = this.length - arr.length; i < arr.length; i++, j++){
            this[j] = arr[i];
        }
        
        return this;
    
    };
    
    let start = performance.now();
    
    const dst = [];
        
    for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        dst.push(arr[i]);
    }
    
    console.log(`pushing: ${performance.now() - start}`);
    
    start = performance.now();
    
    const dst2 = [];
        
    dst2.append(arr);
    
    
    console.log(`appending: ${performance.now() - start}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand if you want to add an Array into another or just make one Array made of two Arrays.

In the last case this is a short way to concatenate Arrays too by using spread syntax:

```js
const arr1 = [1, 2, 3];
const arr2 = [4, 5, 6];
const combinedArray = [...arr1, ...arr2];
console.log(combinedArray);
```

Note:

If you need to preserve the original arrays, this code above is suitable, like the `concat()` method.

The `push()` method will modify your initial Array.